# Update project created with composer create-project

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, composer-php

There are some frameworks like laravel which recommend installation using `create-project`. 
It would be [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917319/1306186) to update projects like this through composer, because

> The composer create-project creates the skeleton with all initial
>   routes in your configuration etc.
>
> From the very very first moment you are starting to change the default
>   routes, removing the default controllers and changing the default
>   views, your project would be out of sync. because meanwhile laravel
>   changes the skeleton to newer versions with some new default routes
>   etc or event changes directory structure.

However, I've recently seen that `phpmyadmin` [recommends](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#installing-using-composer) `composer create-project` as a possible installation method.

As phpmyadmin does not simply provide some skeleton files to be modified by the user, but a complete, finished web-app, I'd like to know what's the best way to update a `phpmyadmin` installation created like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether there is an official way to do this.

According to the docs, `create-project` is the equivalent of:

> doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a `composer install` of the vendors.

If you haven't modified any of the files, I think the easiest way would be to just delete the directory and run `composer create-project` again.

If you have modified some of the files, you could do a git merge (if the project uses git) and run `composer update` again.

If you haven't yet created the project, you could run `create-project` with the `--keep-vcs` flag and then every time you want to update it, you can `cd` to the project and run:

```
git pull origin <version>
composer update
```

If you have already installed the project without `--keep-vcs`, then you'll have to make the directory a git repository and then add the project's repository as remote. To find the project's repository, search for it on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/). For example, for phpmyadmin:

```
cd phpmyadmin
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add initial files"
git remote add git@github.com:phpmyadmin/composer.git
git pull origin <version> --allow-unrelated-histories -Xtheirs 
composer update
```

Some of your changes might be lost with the above `git pull` though so make a backup (and maybe research other ways to merge unrelated histories).

Comment: Unfortunately, using `composer create-project --keep-vcs phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` times out after 300 seconds, probably due to the 150.000+ commits in the repo. This can not worked around, as composer does not allow shallow clones :( I guess the only solution is not to use composer create-project at all and simply use git instead. Are there any additional things `composer-create-project` does apart from `git clone`'-ing?

Comment: Not that I know of.